# Passing arguments in anonymous functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see JavaScript that is written with an argument provided that already has a set value or is an object with methods.  Take this jQuery example for instance:

```
$(".selector").children().each(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

When logging `i`, you would get the value of whatever `i` is in that iteration when looking at the selectors children in the jQuery `each` method.

Take this Node.js example:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

You can see here that `request` and `response` are being passed and they contain their own methods that can be acted on.

To me, this looks like were passing a function to the `createServer` function with two arguments that have methods already attached to them.

My question is a multipart one:

1. Where do these arguments come from?
2. If these are just anon functions, how do they receive arguments that can be acted on like other functions?
3. How do I create functions that can take my own arguments like this??
4. Does this use the power of closures??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> To me, this looks like were passing a function to the createServer function with two arguments that have methods already attached to them.

No.  They were passing a function to `createServer` that takes two arguments.  Those functions will later be called with whatever argument the caller puts in.  e.g.:

```
function caller(otherFunction) {
     otherFunction(2);
 }
caller(function(x) {
    console.log(x); 
});
```

Will print 2.

More advanced, if this *isn't* what you want you can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method belong to all functions, which will create a new function with specified arguments already bound.  e.g.:

```
caller(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
}.bind(null, 3);
});
```

Will now print 3, and the argument 2 passed to the anonymous function will become an unused and unnamed argument.

Anyway, that is a dense example; please check the linked documentation for `bind` to understand how binding works better.

Comment: But how does `request` and `response` in my node example have methods already??  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: What do you mean by "already"? The parameters do not have values until the function is called.

Comment: @SethenMaleno `request` and `response` are just parameters for the `createServer` method. When that method is actually called, it will be passed two objects, representing a request and a response that you can manipulate. Declaring parameters just sets up what the function is expecting; the magic happens when the function is called

Comment: @Ian But where do these objects come from?  Where are they defined at?  If they are just objects with methods defined somewhere in the script, why pass them as arguments?

Comment: @SethenMaleno They are created within node! They aren't globally accessible; they're specific to this `http.createServer` call and only accessible in that scope

Comment: @Ian But WHERE are these made?  Why do we pass them as arguments?  I don't understand this at all.

Comment: @SethenMaleno **You** aren't passing them as arguments. You're declaring them as parameters. Your code says "Call `http.createServer` and pass this function. **When the server is ready**, call that function I just provided and pass it two arguments." In your function, you reference those two arguments as `request` and `response`

Comment: @Ian Okay, so if they are just parameters, where do the methods come from in the body?

Comment: @SethenMaleno You mean like `.write()`?

Comment: @Ian Yes.  Where does that come from?

Comment: @SethenMaleno So, just like normal function parameters, the **parameter names** are just **aliases**. You are just saying "Inside this function, I want the first argument passed to it to be referenced as `request`...and the second argument passed to it to be referenced as `response`". When node actually calls your function, it passes two (very) complex **objects** (the arguments), which have properties/methods (such as `.write()`).

Comment: @Ian I created a jsfiddle to what I think (on a small scale) the code is doing, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/NEyFy/1/

Comment: @SethenMaleno Yes! That's exactly right. I should've just done that in the first place to help explain

Comment: @Ian Nice!  Here is one that I created that does the same thing but it works sort of like an each function: http://jsfiddle.net/FrjHJ/ ... I think it's the same theory.  I got it now.  Thank you for your help, I was completely lost and you didn't quit.  I really appreciate it. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at `$.each` for the example:

```
each: function (obj, callback, args) {
    var value,
    i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike(obj);

    if (args) {
        if (isArray) {
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i in obj) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if (isArray) {
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i in obj) {
                value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

This gets called from

```
$(".selector").children().each(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

like:

```
return $.each.call(this, callback /* this is your function */, args /* which is an additional thing people rarely use*/ )
```

This is the line (in the first block) you want to look at

```
callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);
```

It's calling the callback, and passing the object as the context – this is why you can use `this` in the loop. Then the iteration `i` and then the same object as the context are both sent as arguments to the callback. It's a little bit like magic; until you look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example of passing parameters into anonymous function

```
    var a = 'hello';

    // Crockford
    (function(a){alert(a)}(a));

    // Others
    (function(a){alert(a)})(a);
```

It uses closure, since it's an anonymous function (it actually all depends how you wrote it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are passing functions as arguments.  The functions that you pass will of course have their own arguments.

And, these arguments can be anything including objects which may have their own methods, etc.

`http.createServer` will accept a function and it will know how may arguments that function has.  One way to to do this is to check the `arguments` property of the passed in function.  Or the api developer may have used the actual elements.

The writer of this function will know what is expected as arguments and will document it in the `api documentation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the code for createServer, it'd look something like this:

```
function createServer (handleRequestAndResponseFunction) {
    handleRequestAndResponseFunction(actualRequest, actualReponse);
}
```

ok, no it wouldn't, but it's a simple example. createServer takes a `function` that accepts two arguments.

In more realistic terms, when you pass in that function of two arguments, it does whatever middleware processing and stuff that it needs to, and then calls that function, passing its own request and response variables.