# Where does an anonymous function gets its arguments

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows

I'm learning to develop Windows 8 style applications with the help of a book. The chapter I'm reading focuses on HTML, CSS and JavaScript languages for developing. The application displays in a *ListView* the images you have in the My Pictures Folder and deletes them when the user clicks or taps an image. Here is the code that implements the deletion of an image in the *ListView*:

```
var lv = document.getElementById('lv');
lv.addEventListener('iteminvoked', function (eventObj) {
    eventObj.detail.itemPromise.then(function (listViewItem) {
        var binding = files.dataSource.createListBinding();
        binding.fromIndex(listViewItem.index).then(function (dataItem) {
            var key = dataItem.key;
            files.dataSource.remove(key);
            binding.release();
         });
     });
});
```

My question is, where does the `eventObj` parameter of the anonymous function in the `addEventListener` method gets its value? I have found a similar question asked here: [Passing arguments in anonymous functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195750/passing-arguments-in-anonymous-functions-in-javascript), but i cannot fully understand it. I searched the documentation for `addEventListener` on MSDN but it just says it takes an event handler function, but it doesn't say anything about the parameters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to all the general answers about where eventObj comes from, you're probably interested most in the data type of that object itself. This is always found in the documentation for the event; in your case WinJS.UI.ListView.oniteminvoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Event handlers may be attached to various objects including DOM
>   elements, document, the window object, etc. When an event occurs, an
>   event object is created and passed sequentially to the event
>   listeners.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

An **event listener** or **event handler** can be an anonymous function or named function, it really doesn’t matter. The point is that it’s the *event interface* that defines the event object that is passed to the handler.

To find out exactly the event property from the event you are using, please refer to the windows docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx

Comment: that, too, doesn'T give any explanation on how the event finally ends up inside that nameless function created by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple: whatever function internally calls that callback passes the arguments. See, addEventListener tells the executing Javascript engine to call the callback function you specify whenever an event occurs. The javascript engine saves your anonymous function in some variable - and cann call it later on using that exact variable, passing any number of arguments.

To illustrate it, consider something like this the internal function that handels events (purlely fictional, just to illustrate how it could be done):

```
var callbacks = [];

function addEventListener(newEvent, newCallback) {
    callbacks.push({event : newEvent, callback : newCallback});
}

function handleEvent (someEvent) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < callbacks.length ; i++ ) {
        if (callbacks[i].event == someEvent.name) {
            callbacks[i].callback(someEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Some more explanation:

As javascript is a so-called "functional language", functions are just values of variables.

```
function someFunc () {}
```

is actually just some kind of shortcut (technically it's not, but it does the same thing) for

```
var someFunc = function () {}
```

This having said, it's of cours possible to associate multiple names with one function:

```
var someFunc  = function () {}
var sameFunc  = someFunc;
var stillSame = somefunc;
var alsoSame  = stillSame;
```

and you can call that function using any of those names, including passing arguments of course:

```
var someFunc  = function (arg) { alert(arg); }
var sameFunc  = someFunc;
sameFunc("It worx");
```

You can even call a function without ever naming it:

```
(function () {alert("test")})();<
```

or

```
(function (arg) { alert(arg); })("test")
```

Using this concept to perversion finally leads (long way to go however) to things like the [y-combinator](http://kestas.kuliukas.com/YCombinatorExplained/).

Answer (score 1):

it is a CustomEvent, and all the process is like that:

```
//you add a anonymous function to a specific listener
lv.addEventListener('iteminvoked', function (eventObj) {
    console.log(eventObj===myEvent);
});

//somewhere in your code a CustomEvent gets created based on "iteminvoked" key
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("iteminvoked", {
    itemInfo: {
        name: "yourItem"
    },
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
});

//somewhere when an item gets invoked this code raise the `iteminvoked` trigger
lv.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

all the functions that are passed as a listener are stored based on the key, something like:

```
var observers = {
    "iteminvoked" : [f1, f2],
    //other keys
}
```

it doesn't have anything to do with not having name, the function object is stored in the some kind of array. and `dispatchEvent` goes thru the array and invokes all the functions, and pass the `myEvent` as their parameter. It is a `Observer` pattern, implemented in javascript, I have implemented it once in my own javascript library like:

```
var lv = /*your element*/;
if(observers["iteminvoked"]){
    for(var i=0;i<observables["iteminvoked"].length;i++){
        var func = observables["iteminvoked"][i];
        var o = func.call(lv, myEvent);

        //this line is to support return false
        if(o!==undefined && o===false) break;
    }
}
```

as you can see it is `dispatchEvent` resplonsiblity to invoke all the observers, and your function no matter it has name or not gets invoked with the `lv` as the `this` context and `myEvent` as the parameter.

Comment: that doesn'T explain how that parameter is passed to a function that has "no name".

Comment: @JohannesH. Actually it kind of does, but this is probably happening under the hood of `WinJS.UI` and not in the user’s code.

Comment: Yes, it actually is. The concept can be rebuilt in javascript itself though.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort on the answer I must admit I don't understand much of what you're saying, mostly because this is my first attempt at a dynamic language like JavaScript, so concepts like observables, events and stuff are new to me. Still thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments recieved by the event listener are sent from the `dispatchEvent`, i.e. when the event **dispatched** it passes an event object to your handler.

Refer to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) on how to create and dispatch the event. The event object can vary in structure to convey information to the eventhandler to execute necessary steps. So in your case when you do `lv.dispatchEvent(newevent)` this sends an `newevent` as `eventObj` to your event handler.

Keep in mind there can be multiple eventhandlers listening to an event so the browser maintains a stack for the eventlisteners running them sequentially with each of them passed `eventObj`.

Anonymous function is no different from a named function. In JavaScript functions are first-class objects meaning regular objects. So you can pass them like regular objects(numbers,strings) without having to name them. Only thing is reuse becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand this code is to rewrite it a bit:

```
var lv = document.getElementById('lv'),
    invokeHandler = function (eventObj) {
        var promiseFullfilled = function (listViewItem) {
                var binding = files.dataSource.createListBinding(),
                    anotherPromiseFullfilled = function (dataItem) {
                        var key = dataItem.key;
                        files.dataSource.remove(key);
                        binding.release();
                    };

                binding.fromIndex(listViewItem.index).then(anotherPromiseFullfilled);
            };

        eventObj.detail.itemPromise.then(promiseFullfilled);
    };

    lv.addEventListener('iteminvoked', invokeHandler);
```

This code works just the same, however it is now obvious that `addEventListener` or `then` actually do not know *anything* about the callback functions they are passed with. They can, however, use `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply` to apply arguments:

```
// This is PSEUDOCODE, event model actually works in a totally different way

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventType, callback, bubbles) {
    // callbacks is some internal collection for this specific element, probably available via a closure, looks something like:
    // { 
    //   'someEventType': [callback1, callback2], 
    //   'someOtherEvent': [callback1, callback3, callback4] 
    // }
    callbacks[eventType].push(callback); 
}

// This is called whenever an event is triggered on an element
HTMLElement.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
    callbacks[event.type].forEach( function(callback) {
        return callback.call(this, event); // the callback is called with 'this' set to the element DOM object, and 'event' is the first argument  
    });
    // then it can bubble or cancel depending on the event type and callback results
}
```